# DL160 gen9 P440 SAS cable

Tags: raid, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

We recently bought a new HP Smart Array P440 RAID controller from the local HP reseller store for our HP DL160 gen9 server. (P/N: 783361-425) We want to run ESXi on the server, with three virtual hosts.

We bought the HP Smart Array P440 to upgrade from the current b140i RAID controller. Because the P440 requires to have an internal x8 mini-sas double-wide connector we ordered the HP SAS cable for P440 (P/N: 725593-b21) as listed in the quickspecs document.

After three weeks waiting for the cable we inserted it in the server, the internal x8 mini-sas double-wide connector fits in the RAID controller. However the other side of the cable does not fit because there is no backplane where we can insert the other end with the mini-sas plug.

Maybe it's easier to explain with pictures:

The current cable with B140i looks like this
[current cable with B140i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GG9w.jpg)

The other side of the new cable we bought (P/N: 725593-b21):
[New cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQx0g.jpg)

I contacted the HP enterprice support and the local reseller, but they have no idea which cable I need...

Comment: Maybe I could use an RAID controller adapter to connect both ends to each other?

Answer (score 2):

I would tell 785991-B21

ID found there; http://h20195.www2.hp.com/V2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=4AA5-4154ENW&cc=us&lc=en

I'am just not sure as a simple google search give various picture for it and partsurfer got no picture associated with it..  One picture found look like your older cable but I can't double check my answer

Comment: This is right. The HP reseller should know this, though. (bad service)

Comment: That is for the HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9, right? I need the one for the DL160. I also Googled here: http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04375607.pdf

Comment: And it's a 4LFF server :)